# Why is Android Studio showing: 'Unresolved reference: toolbar_sign_up_activity' despite having a valid android id in the xml file (see screenshots)?

Tags: android, kotlin

Why is Android Studio showing: 'Unresolved reference: toolbar_sign_up_activity' despite having a valid android id by that name in the corresponding xml file (see screenshots)? Also, it shows "No speakable text present" error despite allocation of valid string resources as hints.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWsuu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrYch.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXLNa.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGB4i.png)

Was not expecting such errors and cant see any reason for why Android studio is acting this way.

Answer (score 0):

The `setSupportActionBar()` method accept toolbar not id.

try this :

```
private fun setupActionBar(){
   val toolbar=findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar_sign_up_activity);
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```